# Remote debugging with lldb - wait for process

Tags: ios, macos, remote-debugging, lldb

I know how to wait and attach to a local process (`process attach --name procname --waitfor`).
I also know how to run a remote `debugserver` and connect to it.

But how can I wait for a process to start on a remote host and attach to it?

**EDIT**

I have tried [@Jim's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36460888/1609201), and it seems like the debug server is actually *trying* to attach but *failing*.
I am accepting his answer since it is correct, but I will be happy to know why I can't really debug the process.
FYI I am trying to debug mdmd (mdm daemon service) on a JB iPhone. The process launches for a few seconds to communicate with the mdm server, and then dies.

This is from the target's terminal:

> ~ root# debugserver *:1234
>   debugserver-310.2 for arm64.
>   Listening to port 1234 for a connection from *...
>   Got a connection, waiting for process information for launching or attaching.
>   Attach succeeded, ready to debug.
>   Exiting.

And this is from lldb's:

> (lldb) process connect connect://localhost:1234
>   (lldb) process attach --name mdmd --waitfor
>   error: attach failed: unable to attach

Comment: Normally daemons mark themselves not debuggable, so on any recent darwin based system I would expect the attach to be denied.  For instance, if you had tried to do this on OS X, even as root you would get the same error.  But I don't have any experience with jail-broken devices.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having a similar problem. I'm running lldb client on Linux and lldb-server on Android, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to start up the remote debugserver with only the port to connect to and no other arguments.  In that mode it is driven completely by the lldb connected to it.  So then just do:

```
(lldb) process attach --name procname --waitfor
```

and that will instruct the remote debugserver to wait for that process to show up and then it will attach to it.

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer your question but other people may find it helpful.  On your jailbroken device (with the Electra iOS11 JB) you can issue the `wait-for` in a slightly different order...

This gives you the ability to debug over USB on a jailbroken device.

```
### On macOS machine
iproxy 6666 6666 &  (google `iproxy` to find setup instructions)

### On Jailbroken device
root# /Developer/usr/bin/debugserver localhost:6666 -waitfor APPNAME
< now open the app >

### on macOS machine
lldb
(lldb) process connect connect://localhost:6666
```

This is great as you start at the app-startup.  However, the downside is lldb does not control `STDOUT`.  Don't expect  `NSLog` to show on the lldb screen.  It will show on the `Console.app`.